# How to only show documents to specific users in a shared database?

Tags: security, database-design, couchdb, ionic3, pouchdb

I'm managing a multiuser app using Ionic 3.x, PouchDB, CouchDB and a node.js server running Superlogin. The app is steadily growing and I want to introduce a new feature.

My app has normal users and superusers. Each normal and superuser in my application gets it's own user database. There is also a shared database, let's call it the generaldb.

And here's my problem: Both users can create documents. These documents are synced to the userdb as well as to the general db. These documents have, amongst other things, a keyword (e.g. "colour": "green"). Superusers have access to a specific key. (In the above example that would mean that there are for example 5 superusers who can access the key green.)

Now, no normal user should be able to read, update or write other user's documents on the generaldb. Superusers should be able to read, update or write documents in the generaldb depending on which key they have access to. But they should not be allowed to change documents that don't match their key.

1. How can I restrict access for normal users in the generaldb, so that only documents created by themselves are synced to their devices and so that they couldn't change other users documents?
2. How can I ensure, superusers can change normal users documents, as long as they have access to the correct key?
3. How can I ensure superusers cannot change their own key, so that when number 2 is accomplished, they cannot manually work around the system?

One of the ideas of mine is to only let the users access their own db and have the shared db only accessible by superusers and then do a filtered replication of the userdb to the shared db. But this only solves 1 and seems very inefficient.